# Missing GWT Designer Features

Tags: user-interface, gwt, ide, gwt-designer

I am using the latest GWT Designer version 8.1.1.r36x201012191024 in SpringSource Tool Suite. From the official [user guide](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/index.html), it should have feature like Factories, Morphing etc. [image: Morphing].

---

However, I can't find such features. What I am getting is just like the below.[image].

---

Am I missing some step to enable advance features? I found out the user guide is exactly same as [WindowBuilder Pro](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/index.html). Are these features only for WindowBuilder Pro, which is for desktop Java application? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contacted [Google/Instantiations](http://forums.instantiations.com/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=5670&p=18428#p18428), the only one of those features that is relevant for **UiBinder**-based UIs is **morphing** and that is on the list to implement at some time **in the future**. If you are using **Java**-based UI, you are able to see **all features**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 
GWT Designer Editor 8.1.1.r36x201012191114
GWT Designer    8.1.1.r36x201012191837
and I can see the above features that you have mentioned as missing.

Comment: Are you using UiBinder? Thanks.

Comment: Nopes. I'm using the latest GWT Designer in Eclipse